# SQL update tableA.column where the column and value is in a separate table

Tags: sql

I have tableA with the columns ID, ColumnHeader, Value.

I'm trying to update tableB where ID, and the value in tableB.ColumnHeader with tableB.Value. 
Essentially, the column headers for tableB are in a column in Table A and not column headers themselves.

I'm stuck on specifying the table name. For example, how do I run this query when I only have tablename.____ where the blank is in a column in a separate table?

```
update tableB set table.____ .....
```

As seen in the screenshot below, in Table B, 4 should become 1, and 8 should become 2, and 12 should become 3. Thanks so much.

[image: screenshot of sample tables A and B]

Comment: I have removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Which database are you using ? MySQL, oracle or other ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

this is a example from Northwind database:

`UPDATE dbo.Products
SET dbo.Products.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
FROM Products
    INNER JOIN dbo.Categories c ON dbo.Products.CategoryID = c.CategoryID`

I am not getting which table and column you want to update with which table and column.
also relationship is not clear.

Comment: The tables are not related, I'm updating table B with info in table A

Comment: tableB.ColumnName and tableA.ColumnName? and add some output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense to me. Are you trying to update table B or A? Are there like values in table B and A that you want updated?

The basic code is as shown below:

```
update tableb 
set column id = 'value you're updating' 
where column id = 'value you're looking for' --always make this unique like a key etc.
```